Mobile Keyboard Closes Immediately on iPhone When Clicking Input or Text Editor in React Application
I’m experiencing a strange issue in my React application that only occurs on iPhones (tested in both Safari and Chrome).
The app contains standard input fields and a text editor. When I tap on an input or the text editor, the mobile keyboard briefly opens but immediately closes, making it impossible to type anything.
example: https://streamable.com/n2k7q5
This issue:
Only happens on iPhones (both Safari and Chrome).
Does not occur on Android devices.
Does not occur on desktop browsers, even when using mobile resolution in responsive design mode.
I’ve verified that there are no onBlur or similar events being triggered unintentionally, and I can’t find anything in the code that would explain this behavior.
When I comment out this part of my code:

<div className={profileStyles.aboutEdit}>
  <label htmlFor="file-upload" className={profileStyles.picturesAddBox}>
    <div className={profileStyles.picturesAddBoxContent}>
      <div className={profileStyles.picturesAddPlus}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
      </div>
      <h4>Add new media</h4>
    </div>
  </label>
  <input
    id="file-upload"
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    onChange={handleImageUpload}
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      opacity: 0,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      zIndex: 999,
      background: 'blue',
    }}
  />
</div>

And replace it with a simple <div>Something</div> and also If I remove the padding-top: 90px; from the
aboutviewContent
class in my CSS, the issue resolves, but it is not solution, i need file input for upload image.
Here’s my full code:
<div className="container widget-main">
  <div className="row aboutviewContent">
    <div className="col-lg-12">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          {file || (!!data && data?.image) ? (
            <div className="aboutImageBox">
              <Image
                className="aboutEditPageImage"
                width={100}
                height={100}
                src={
                  file
                    ? file
                    : 'https://cdn.widgera.com/company-widget/' +
                      (compId == 'publish'
                        ? context?.companyContextInfo?.id
                        : compId) +
                      '/image/' +
                      data?.image
                }
                alt="about"
              />
              <div className={profileStyles.picturesEditBoxBtns}>
                <div className={profileStyles.picturesEditBoxUpdate}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCamera} />
                </div>
                <div className={profileStyles.picturesEditBoxDelete}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <input
                id="file-upload"
                type="file"
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImageUpload}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  opacity: 0,
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  zIndex: 999,
                  background: 'blue',
                }}
              />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className={profileStyles.aboutEdit}>
              <label
                htmlFor="file-upload"
                className={profileStyles.picturesAddBox}
              >
                <div className={profileStyles.picturesAddBoxContent}>
                  <div className={profileStyles.picturesAddPlus}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
                  </div>
                  <h4>Add new media</h4>
                </div>
              </label>
              <input
                id="file-upload"
                type="file"
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImageUpload}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  opacity: 0,
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  zIndex: 999,
                  background: 'blue',
                }}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-9">
          <Tiptap content={content} setContent={setContent} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={profileStyles.aboutChangeBtns}>
    <button
      className="btn-md-tertiary"
      onClick={() => {
        props.setModal([]);
      }}
    >
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button
      className="btn-md-primery ms-2"
      onClick={() => handleSave()}
    >
      Save Changes
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
css
.aboutviewContent {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: var(--generic-white);
  height: calc(100vh - 149px);
  padding-top: 90px; /* Removing this resolves the issue, if i have commented div of input*/
}

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
